# Is there an efficient way to clean up [digraphs] mistagging?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[digraphs](/questions/tagged/digraphs) is the tag for the orthographic concept. Graph theory uses "digraph" as an abbreviation for [directed-graph](/questions/tagged/directed-graph), which has resulted in some mistagging.

Now many of the latter posts also have tags like [graph-theory](/questions/tagged/graph-theory), and it's quite unlikely that there is going to be an overlap between the orthographic [digraphs](/questions/tagged/digraphs) and [graph-theory](/questions/tagged/graph-theory). So perhaps we can do a conditional retagging?

Comment: [digraph] does not seem to be used?

Comment: Whoops, it's indeed [digraphs] plural.

Comment: At 56 questions with that tag, I'd say it's easy enough to do it by hand. Though of course digraphs and trigraphs have a [a different meaning as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) apart from the purely orthographic concept.

Comment: It seems to make sense to leave [tag:directed-graph] as is. And have [tag:digraphs] mean one of the other things and create a tag for the third meaning (no idea what though), and live with the mistagging. If questions about either orthographic or programming digraphs are rare enough, we might even just get rid of one of those completely.

Comment: Lo and behold: a question that needs BOTH tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529872/what-is-the-best-data-structure-and-algorithm-for-comparing-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 2):

The efficient way turned out to do it manually.